# Filter rows to return the exact relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, many-to-many

I have two tables, `expenses` and `categories`, they have a many-to-many relationship through the table `expenses_categories`. I'm trying to implement a filter by categories, lets say that I provided the id for the categories A and B, I want to return the expenses who only have A and B. For example:

- Expense X have Category A, B, and C
- Expense Y have Category A and B
- Expense Z have Category B

I want to return only the Expense Y

I'm using PostgreSQL by the way. I really need to learn how to do this kind of stuff.

Categories

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TV |
| 2 | CC |
| 3 | NET |

ExpensesCategories

| expense_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

I want to get all the Expenses that have ONLY the Categories 1 and 2.
In that case, I expect to only get the Expense 1

| expense_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Comment: Can you provide some other, useful information about your issue (e.g. examples of the tables, expected results, etc.)?

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo, ok, done, I hope its clearer now. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `expense_id` and use `STRING_AGG()` in the `HAVING` clause to collect all the `category_id`s of each `expense_id` and compare it to a string like `'1,2'` which contains the `category_id`s that you want in ascending order as a comma separated list:

```
SELECT expense_id
FROM ExpensesCategories
GROUP BY expense_id
HAVING STRING_AGG(category_id::text, ',' ORDER BY category_id) = '1,2';
```

If you want all the rows of these `expense_id`s in `ExpensesCategories`, use the above query as a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT expense_id
  FROM ExpensesCategories
  GROUP BY expense_id
  HAVING STRING_AGG(category_id::text, ',' ORDER BY category_id) = '1,2'
)
SELECT * 
FROM ExpensesCategories
WHERE expense_id IN (SELECT expense_id FROM cte);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8859c67f075501a592fbd21f77e0b697).

Comment: Thank you very much! Im not that good at SQL, can you recommend me some reading/course? I really need to improve. Thank you again

Comment: @user3344570 online you can find many sources about SQL. One I can recommend, because it's free and it has step by step tutorials is: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com (since you are using postgresql).